# Simple proof that non-linear DE's do no not satisfy superposition?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, examples-counterexamples

I'm wondering if there's a simple proof that solutions to non-linear differential equations do not satisfy the superposition principle?

Some explicit examples would also be great.

Cheers!

Comment: It depends what your definition of linear is in this case. I think it wouldn't be unreasonable to say "a DE is linear if linear combinations of solutions are solutions" which is pretty much "a DE is linear if it satisfies superposition"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For such cases the simplest example that comes to mind usually works. Consider d.e. $y'=y^2$. It has solutions $y_c(x)=\frac 1{c-x}\,$ for $c\in \mathbb R$. But functions $y_1+y_2$ and $2y_1$ are not solutions.

But it cannot be said that all solutions of any nonlinear equation do not satisfy the superposition principle. Consider, for example, equation $(y'')^2=0$.

Comment: Is there some general proof (barring trivial solutions), or am I looking for something that can't be found?

Comment: @trolle3000 Proof of that exactly? An example is given in the answer. Also given an example of a non-linear equation all solutions of which satisfy the superposition principle.

Answer (score 0):

Superposition theorem only works for linear differential equations.  Reason is For a non-linear differential equation we are using transformations that would be the solution.  Again if we think for other solution and their linear combination seems not at all a solution.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question, and the formulation is unclear.